# In the risc-v architecture, what do the bits returned by the mulh[[s]u] operation look like?

Tags: 64-bit, multiplication, cpu-registers, riscv, instruction-set

TLDR: given 64 bit registers `rs1(signed) = 0xffff'ffff'ffff'fff6` and `rs2(unsigned) = 0x10` does the riscv mulhsu instruction return `0x0000'0000'0000'000f` or `0xffff'ffff'ffff'ffff` or something else entirely to rd?

I am working on implementing a simulated version of the RiscV architecture and have run into a snag when implementing the RV64M mulh[[s]u] instruction. I'm not sure if mulhsu returns a signed or unsigned number. If it does return a signed number, then what is the difference between mulhsu and mulh?

here is some pseudocode demonstrating the problem (s64 and u64 denote signed and unsigned 64-bit register respectively)

```
rs1.s64 = 0xffff'ffff'ffff'fff6;   //-10
rs2.u64 = 0x10;                    // 16

execute(mulhsu(rs1, rs2));

// which of these is correct? Note: rd only returns the upper 64 bits of the product
EXPECT_EQ(0x0000'0000'0000'000f, rd);
EXPECT_EQ(0xffff'ffff'ffff'ffff, rd);
EXPECT_EQ(<some other value>, rd);
```

Should rd be signed? unsigned?

From the instruction manual:

MUL performs an XLEN-bit × XLEN-bit multiplication of rs1 by rs2 and places the lower XLEN bits
in the destination register. MULH, MULHU, and **MULHSU** perform the same multiplication but return
the upper XLEN bits of the full 2 × XLEN-bit product, for signed × signed, unsigned × unsigned,
and **signed rs1×unsigned rs2 multiplication**, respectively. If both the high and low bits of the same
product are required, then the recommended code sequence is: MULH[[S]U] rdh, rs1, rs2; MUL
rdl, rs1, rs2 (source register specifiers must be in same order and rdh cannot be the same as rs1 or
rs2). Microarchitectures can then fuse these into a single multiply operation instead of performing
two separate multiplies.

Comment: It is an interesting question, given most architectures don't offer signed x unsigned.  However, the answer is almost certainly that the result is signed, because signed x unsigned will be negative when "signed" is negative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer for your question is :`EXPECT_EQ(0xffff'ffff'ffff'ffff, rd);`.

mulhsu will do a multiplication of a sign extend of rs1.s64 and a zero extend rs2.u64.
You can see that in the compiler machine description `riscv.md`.

so mulhsu (64 bits) will return  the equivalent of :
`((s128) rs1.s64 * (u128) rs2.u64) >> 64`.  where s128 is a signed 128 int and u128 an unsigned 128 int.

the difference between the three mul is:
mulhsu is a multiplication between a sign extended register  and a zero extended register.
mulh is a multiplication of two sign extended registers.
mulhu is a multiplication of two zero extended registers.